# How do I make a Protractor-test wait for multiple elements without relying on SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER for synchronization?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, selenium-webdriver, async-await, protractor

**[Similar questions have been asked and answered before, but the available answers rely on SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER for synchronisation.]**

I'm running a test-environment that handles all asynchronous activity with async/await. The AUT loads something in the dom like

```
<span class="bicon-lock_closed" data-month="8" data-year="2020"></span>
<span class="bicon-lock_closed" data-month="9" data-year="2020"></span>
<span class="bicon-lock_closed" data-month="10" data-year="2020"></span>
<span class="bicon-lock_closed" data-month="11" data-year="2020"></span>
```

At least one of these elements is always present. Protractor needs to wait for the expected condition that at least one more will become present. This is what I got:

```
let lockIconArray: ElementArrayFinder = $$( "span.bicon-lock_closed" );

await browser.wait( Utils.presenceOfAll(lockIconArray, 2) , Data.TIMEOUT.M);
await lockIconArray.count().then( async (numberOfLocks) => {
   await console.log( "Number of elements present: " + numberOfLocks );
   await expect( numberOfLocks ).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(2);
} );
```

It's calling this method of the static class 'Utils':

```
public static async presenceOfAll(elements: ElementArrayFinder, minCountNo: number): Promise<boolean> {
      return Promise.resolve( elements.count().then( (count) => {
            return count >= minCountNo;
      } ) );
}
```

Protractor doesn't appear to wait at all. This is logged to the console immediately:

> Number of elements present: 1

> Expected 1 to be greater than or equal 2.

I assume that this can be solved by using another 'await',  right before 'presenceOfAll':

```
await browser.wait( await presenceOfAll(mEditor.lockIconArray, 2) , Data.TIMEOUT.M);
```

Am I on the right path? And if so: How do I make the 'presenceOfAll'-method resolve that second promise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, you can write your function instead of using `ExtectedConditions` library. In this case, you could do

```
let lockIconArray = $$('.bicon-lock_closed');
await browser.wait(
  async () => (await lockIconArray.count()) > 2, 
  5000, 
  `message on failure`
);
```

Comment: Wow, I cannot believe that this code actually works as intended... It’s amazing how the solution so simple!